# How to Delete a Specific Object From The Arrayof Objects in MongoDB Casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

mydata is look like below:-

```
    {
    "categories": [
    {
        "categoryname": "Eletronics",
        "categoryId": "89sxop",
        "displayname": "Eletronics",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "subcategoryname": "laptop",
                "subcategoryId": "454",
                "displayname": "Laptop"
            },
            {
                "subcategoryname": "camera",
                "subcategoryId": "sony123",
                "displayname": "Camera"
            }
        ]
      }
      ]
      }
```

I want to delete a specific object from a Subcategories Array

we are Trying like below code:-(This is to Delete Category)

```
val removingData = $pull(MongoDBObject("categories" -> MongoDBObject("categoryName" -> "Entertainment")))
```

this code is for removing Particular category.

But I Want To Remove ONE or MORE subCategories from particular category.
The subCategory(Ex:-i want to Delete camera Object from mydata) from the Electronics category

Expected Output:-(after deleting the camera Object)

```
{
"categories": [
    {
        "categoryname": "Eletronics",
        "categoryId": "89sxop",
        "displayname": "Eletronics",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "subcategoryname": "laptop",
                "subcategoryId": "454",
                "displayname": "Laptop"
            }

        ]
    }
]
}
```

Best Regards
GSY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `$pull` operator, specifying the `subcategories` array and the condition used to pick the elements to remove. The `$` operator can be used to select the `subcategories` array of the specific `categories` element you're interested in. See the [Update Array Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) docs of mongo for details. Something like the following should work:

```
val query = MongoDBObject("categories.categoryname" -> "Electronics")
val removingData = $pull("categories.$.subcategories" -> MongoDBObject("subcategoryname" -> "camera"))

collection.update(query, removingData)
```

If you want to remove multiple subcategories, you can use the `$or` operator to specify multiple `subcategoryname`s

Comment: Hi Kong its not working we are getting error like below:-  TypeMismatch Found Required Imports.DBObjects actual String,Import.DBObjects And We Tried Another Way Also:- val removingData = $pull(MongoDBObject("categories.$.subcategories" -> MongoDBObject("subcategoryname" -> "camera"))) but this query not deleting mydata...

Comment: What version of casbah are you using? I ran the code above on the sample data you pasted and it removed the subcategory as expected with casbah 2.6.3. The only change I made was correcting the spelling of "Electronics" in the categoryname.